# Once my push navigation menu has been opened I lose my hover effects

Tags: javascript, css, menu, navigation, hover

So, I'm not sure how I can create a demo to show what I mean but basically I have a push navigation menu (see: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp SIDENAV WITH PUSH AND OPACITY)
I have it working almost perfectly, I had to adjust the javascript in order to make the CSS for header (and a couple other elements) of my page to change when the menu is opened and when the menu is closed the CSS returns to how it was before the menu was opened HOWEVER ... after the menu has been opened and then closed the hover effects for my header no longer work.

here is my css for my header:

```
#header {
    width: 95%;
    height: 60px;
    left: 2.5%;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
#header:hover {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0px;
    }
```

and here is my javascript:

```
 function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.getElementById("header").style.position = "relative";
    document.getElementById("header").style.left = "0px";
    document.getElementById("header").style.opacity = "0.9";
    document.getElementById("header").style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("header").style.borderRadius = "0px";
    document.getElementById("cover").style.marginTop = "-80px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)";
    }

    function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    document.getElementById("header").style.position = "fixed";
    document.getElementById("header").style.left = "2.5%";
    document.getElementById("header").style.opacity = "0.8";
    document.getElementById("header").style.width = "95%";
    document.getElementById("header").style.borderRadius = "0px 0px 30px 30px";
    document.getElementById("cover").style.marginTop = "0px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
```

I have it working exactly how I want except after closing the sidenav my hover classes no longer work hope someone can point out what I'm missing.

Comment: also just noticed when I open and close the menu everything moves smoothly except for my heading which moves smoothly upon opening the menu but upon closing the menu it jumps back to place the heading is in my header div between a float:left element and a float:right element both of the floating elements move back smoothly when the menu is closed but the for some reason does not.

Comment: You will find your code much more maintainable if, instead of changing individual style attributes on your element, you add/remove a class on `openNav`/`closeNav`. As well as providing a single point of control, it helps separate your logic from your layout design, AND ensures that once you've removed the class on `closeNav`, your element will behave exactly as it did before you called `openNav`.

Comment: So something along the lines of this would work better? 


function openNav() {
$('#MyElement').addClass('open');
}

function openNav() {
$('#MyElement').removeClass('open');
}

Comment: That's what I'd do.